# Python: Working with columns inside a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good evening,

is it possible to calculate with - let's say - two columns inside a dataframe and add a third column with the fitting result?

Dataframe (original):

```
name        time_a      time_b
name_a      08:00:00    09:00:00
name_b      07:45:00    08:15:00
name_c      07:00:00    08:10:00
name_d      06:00:00    10:00:00
```

Or to be specific...is it possible to obtain the difference of two times (time_b - time_a) and create a
new column (time_c) at the end of the dataframe?

Dataframe (new):

```
name        time_a      time_b      time_c
name_a      08:00:00    09:00:00    01:00:00
name_b      07:45:00    08:15:00    00:30:00
name_c      07:00:00    08:10:00    01:10:00
name_d      06:00:00    10:00:00    04:00:00
```

Thanks and a good night!

Comment: What is the type of your `time` columns?

Comment: The datatype is "datetime.time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns are in `datetime` or `timedelta` format:

```
# New column is a timedelta object
df["time_c"] = (df["time_b"] - df["time_a"])
```

If your columns are in `datetime.time` format *(which it appears they are)*:

```
def time_diff(time_1,time_2):
  """returns the difference between time 1 and time 2 (time_2-time_1)"""
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  time_1 = datetime.datetime.combine(now,time_1)
  time_2 = datetime.datetime.combine(now,time_2)
  return time_2 - time_1

# Apply the function
df["time_c"] = df[["time_a","time_b"]].apply(lambda arr: time_diff(*arr), axis=1)
```

Alternatively, you can convert to a timedelta by first converting to a string:

```
df["time_a"]=pd.to_timedelta(df["time_a"].astype(str))
df["time_b"]=pd.to_timedelta(df["time_b"].astype(str))
df["time_c"] = df["time_b"] - df["time_a"]
```

Comment: Before that you might want to convert it to `timedelta`: `df["time_b"]=pd.to_timedelta(df["time_b"])`

Comment: No need @GrzegorzSkibinski – by default, new column with be a timedelta.

Comment: Assuming the input columns are both `timedelta` (which is what I meant actually).

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I get an error message, saying: "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time". Don't know if it's important, but I'm getting my data from a PostgreSQL-Database into a Django-Project. Using the command "read_frame" for my query.

Comment: Can you verify the dtype of your columns @finethen

Comment: @YaakovBressler The columns that inherit the times are listed as "object"

Comment: What does the following code result in? `type(df["time_b"].to_list()[0])`

Comment: Modified the answer for your issue @finethen